# R How to get only line numbers from output?

Tags: r

this is my code and I would like to get only line number 2174 as output.
Note that the first output row will be always disregarded, so I just care about the 2nd and just to see the number of that line, in this case: 2174

```
e[which(e$obs_pval==min(e$obs_pval)),]
              snp     obs_pval
1    1.852962e-07 1.852962e-07
2174 4.971520e+07 1.852962e-07
```

Comment: just use `which` if all you want are the indices.

Comment: `e[which(e$obs_pval==min(e$obs_pval))[2],]` (for a poor hardcoded solution)

Comment: It is hard to tell what criteria you want to use to get only 2174 and not 1. The p value is the same in both. Do you want the last row where p value is minimized? The row with highest snp?

Comment: the first output row will be always disregarded, so I just care about the 2nd and just to see the number of that line, in this case: 2174

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `min` call results in multiple rows sharing the minimum value, which is why more than one row is displayed.

Do you always just want the last row if there are multiple values that match your `min` call?  If so, then you can wrap it in `tail()` :

```
tail(e[which(e$obs_pval == min(e$obs_pval)),], 1)
```

To just get the index:

```
tail(which(e$obs_pval == min(e$obs_pval)), 1)
```

or:

```
which(e$obs_pval == min(e$obs_pval))[length(which(e$obs_pval == min(e$obs_pval)))]
```

Comment: yes, but I want a command which will just give me this value: 2174, nothing else

Comment: Edited the post to just give the last index value of 2174